# Do I need to use three-conductor cable for lighting outlets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've recently had a metal garage put in. I had an electrician friend run power from the house to the garage, he installed an electrical box with 50 amps, and 1 receptacle outlet. (I just wanted some electric before winter hit us).

I plan to run the wire myself and hook up the all the outlets with 12/2 wire. I'm going to put outlets on my ceiling beams and have plug in LED work lights (6 outlets, 6 Lights). I want these to work off of a switch I'm going to install.

Do I need to run 12/3 wire to all the outlets, or do I just run 12/3 from the switch to one outlet and from that outlet run 12/2 to the others to connect them all?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the electrician installed a 50A subpanel?  Are you going to install breakers and wire outlets from them?  If so there are a lot of details you need to learn about.   IMO if you're using plug-in lights on exposed beams it's easier, cheaper and compliant to just use extension cords to connect them all.  Install one switched outlet to plug them into.     If you don't like the idea of extension cords, buy hard-wired fixtures.  They cost more but installing six outlets, one for each light, costs money too and is a lot more work.

Comment: Several things - Why are you running 12 Ga wire to LED lights? 14Ga is all you need (with a 15A breaker) for that. If you want the overhead outlets just to provide switched lights, you don't need *any* /3 wire. /2 to the switch, /2 from the switch to the lights. Please [edit] to include pictures of your panel. Take the [tour].

Comment: @Ecnerwal  It would depend if he is only using the outlets just for the LEDs, or planing to also use them to power tools, heaters.

Comment: Please upload a picture showing the "50A box". Hopefully that is a subpanel. Is the garage attached to the house? (That determines whether you need separate ground rods or not.) What state are you in? (That determines NEC version, which can affect AFCI and GFCI requirements, among other things.)

Comment: No non-lighting use is mentioned, and the ceiling beams in most steel garages are out of practical reach from the floor range,  - but I did say "if."

Comment: The use of 12/2 and 12/3 indicates you're in the US, what city/state? Electrical codes vary and it's hard to give good advice without knowing.

Comment: Additionally, _why_ do you think you need to use 12/3 to wire these outlets? What issue do you think this will solve?

Comment: /3 wiring is needed for a switch loop in order to provide neutral in the switch box. If you wire up from panel to switch to switched devices (whether receptacles or lights) then you only need /2 - hot/neutral from panel to switch, switched hot/neutral from switch to devices.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 20 amp circuit you need to run 12/2with ground this is 3 wire.
Running 12/3 w ground would be 4 wire and a waste.
If you use a 15 amp breaker you can use a smaller gauge wire 14/2w ground would be a little less cost due to the smaller amount of copper used.

If you want to have receptacles that are hot at the lights when the light is off that would require the x/3 wire. Note even on ceilings in a garage or out building all receptacles are required to be GFCI protected.
I hard wire my lights so I don’t have to add GFCI protection.

Comment: May want to add that gfci reset can't be high up, so either gfci breaker ($) or arrange so first receptacle in the circuit is lower.

Answer (score -2):

For your consideration, using the outlet already installed, the light fixtures already purchased, plus six piggyback extension cords, an inline switch and some zip ties you can get this done in an hour for $50.

(If your lights have a ground pin you can get grounded piggyback cords).

[image]

**EDIT**: Acknowledging comments about problems with the images I initially grabbed for this answer, here are a couple of similar products that achieve the same thing more safely.  A cord with outlets spaced at 5 feet and all grounded, and a switch that isn't ridiculously unsafe.  There are many other ways to achieve the same thing.

[image]

Comment: a) We don't know what kind of receptacle OP already has - likely has a 15A or 20A next to a 50A subpanel, but *could* be a 50A receptacle, not clear yet. b) The pictures you have here show a wacky mix of 15A and 20A connectors - not safe and likely not UL or ETL listed. Plus any new receptacles *must* be grounded, so any extension cords used should be grounded as well.

Comment: That switch unit's receptacle is a ***blatant violation.*** Don't buy sketchy unlisted imported electrics, the house they burn down could be yours.

Comment: @Ecnerwal you're right!  I did not pay close enough attention to the images I grabbed and the unsafe outlet end was not part of my point.   But I'll leave it up because your comment is instructive, and hopefully OP can find actual components that are safe AND economical.

Comment: "Relying on Amazon as a source" is an error you've made several times.   Around here we've learned that 90% of what's in their catalog is cheap Cheese crud that ignores our safety rules (UL White Book and NEC). It helps if the item is "Sold by: Amazon" and not a 3rd party seller, but even those items are vulnerable to counterfeits.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine FWIW, I rely on Amazon as a source for  *imagery* to illustrate solution concepts here, more than I do for actual products where I'm more discerning (but you don't have the opportunity to see what I actually buy).  And hence I include, here, only images and not links.  My carelessness, if it even is that, is guided partly by the "no shopping" rules here, which I'm not a fan of, but if I'm not making actual purchase recommendations I frankly don't have to worry so much about whether the thing behind an anonymous image is UL approved.  It's the concept that matters.

Comment: And also FWIW ... my carelessness in *this instance* was inarguable ... that "everything Amps" cord is crazy, and I acknowledge it.  But it's my fault, not Amazon's and I actually think it's helpful to leave these mistakes and the ensuing discussion here.

Comment: Even if the device was listed it would not be code compliant for permanent wiring. cordage can not be used for permanent wiring and this is a photo of cordage, so although a concept it would not be “legal in the US”

Comment: @EdBeal I'm  interested in the intersection of professional and consumer behavior.  Can the lens of a licensed electrician, "used for permanent wiring", be applied to a homeowner using an extension cord for a plug-in device?  What is "permanent" in that context? When is the professional view appropriate?  I do not think that every floor lamp in every living room in the country that is plugged in via an extension cord is "illegal".  Right?  So what's different with OP here?  (If you're going to answer we should probably move it to chat).

Comment: @jay613 I hear you, you're using it only as a guide for which products exist in the market.  But as Ed says, Amazon will show you products *for which no UL-listed equivalent can possibly exist* because the product is inherently a Code violation.  Just off the top of my head, anything involving NEMA 10.  So I would rely on sites like HomeDepot.com, or at least make sure the item says "Sold by: amazon", as their *own* items generally comply with Code.

Comment: Mounting an extension cord with zip ties would be considered permanent, this is why a receptacle is normally required within 6’ inside habitable rooms. electrical code doesn't like extension cords to start with in a commercial or industrial location that can be a fine.